# Retrive data from array & Store as variable using php

Tags: php, arrays

Actually I can't understand how I will explain my problem. I am trying to give an example. In my php code I got a array like this:

`Array ( [0] => E-mail [1] => Newsletter )`

I want to retrieve all the value from this array & want to store it in `$result`. I tried with `foreach` function. But I can't store all the result in `$result` as because it's changing each time & printing separate value. Anyone can help me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with `$result = Array( [0] => E-mail [1] => Newsletter )` ?

Comment: Thanks, Actually I want to print the value of $result but output will be like this E-mail, Newsletter.

Comment: Post your code please. Where did that "Array ( [0] => E-mail [1] => Newsletter )" came from? From a var_dump() or a print_r or what?

Comment: `foreach ($data1 as $k => $v) {
    $result .= $v;
}

echo $result;` It's working just fine. But showing output like this `E-mailNewsletter`. Can I put a `,` between Email & Newsletter. I want like this: `E-mail,Newsletter`.

Comment: Do you want to convert array to string, actually? http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Not actually, I just want to combined all the value of a array in a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $result .= $v;
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks it will work but do you know how I will insert `,` between the result. You code output will be like this `E-mailNewsletter`. But I want to be `E-mail,Newsletter`. Actually I want to insert extra html tag also. Like `<p>`